# I want show add to cart popup window onclick of view cart link using jquery,javascript or asp

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please check bellow link:

http://v1098050.jkgeyrewb7wh.demo10.volusion.com/ProductDetails.asp?ProductCode=MacFRC

Click on Add to Cart button it shows add to cart popup window 
I want to show that add to cart popup window after clicking on View Cart link.
Remember I dont have code of add to cart means I cant change that code only I can access its id's and classes.Only after doing view source I can see code or script for that.
How to do it??

Comment: Please make your question more clear. What do you mean, "don't have code of add to cart"? Do you mean that you can't write additional code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="" onclick="return addToCart(this.form, this);" id="btnaddtocart1">View Cart</a>
```

You get the wrong context to function addToCart, so it returs an error.
What you need to do, is to put right DOMObjects into function:

```
<a href="" onclick="return addToCart(document.MainForm, document.getElementsByClassName('vCSS_input_addtocart')[0]);" id="btnaddtocart1">View Cart</a>
```

And you also need to get some beginners books on JS and HTML.